# How to access JSON object from xml2js in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm using xml2js to convert some xml to json in Angular like so:

```
showData() {
    xml2js.parseString(this.xml, (err, result) => {
      this.text = result;
      console.log(this.text);
    })
  }
```

It works great and I'm getting JSON in my console but I'm having trouble figuring out how to access specific data. Here is what the JSON format looks like:
[image]

I want to access the properites `id`, `maxlength`, `name`, and `type` within `UIElement`. I want to console.log and use the values in these properties but cannot figure out how to do so.

Comment: `console.log(this.text['cm:property-placeholder']['cm:default-properties][0]['UIElement'][0]['$'])` to get the object. then from there you add `id`, `maxlength`, etc to the end to get the individual elements

Comment: @rhavelka I had originally tried that but I receive the error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: do you know if its is on the `cm:default-properties` or the `UIElement` that you were getting the error. I will update my answer as we figure things out

Comment: I missed the `UIInput` layer in my comment and my answer. I will update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do first is get your UIElement array in into its own array. So you will do something like this

```
const uiElmentArray = this.text['cm:property-placeholder']['cm:default-properties'][0]['UIInput'][0]['UIElement'];

/**
uiElementArray = [
    {$: {id: 'customerName', ...}},
    {$: {id: 'mm_test_aggregate.interval', ...}},
    ...
]
**/
```

From there you can map the contents to get rid of the `$` from the array

```
const updatedArray = uiElementArray.map(uiElement => uiElement.$);

/**
updatedArray = [
    {id: 'customerName', ...},
    {id: 'mm_test_aggregate.interval', ...},
    ...
];
**/
```

From there you can loop through your elements to display them

```
updatedArray.forEach(uiElement => {
   console.log(uiElment)
});
```

Making the final code look something like this:

```
showData() {
    xml2js.parseString(this.xml, (err, result) => {
      const uiElementArray = result['cm:property-placeholder']['cm:default-properties'][0]['UIInput'][0]['UIElement'];
      const updatedArray = uiElementArray.map(uiElement => uiElement.$);
      updatedArray.forEach(uiElement => {
          console.log(uiElment)
      });
    })
  }
```

which can be condensed down to something like this

```
showData() {
    xml2js.parseString(this.xml, (err, result) => {
      this.myData = result['cm:property-placeholder']['cm:default-properties'][0]['UIInput'][0]['UIElement'].map(uiElement => uiElement.$);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Now getting the error `Cannot read property 'cm:property-placeholder' of undefined`

Comment: That was a typo on my end. I have `this.text['cm:property-placeholder']` when it should be `result['cm:property-placeholder']`. I updated my code

Comment: Yeah I just caught that too. It's working great. Thank you!